# Creating a reference to a Firebase database from a cloud function and iterating through its children

Tags: javascript, firebase, foreach, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a firebase cloud function that gets called on the write of a specific child value. In the function I would like to iterate through data in a different child that shares the same parent.

The goal of the function is to iterate through a list of coordinates and return the number of points that are within a region. I'm having issues with two things:

1. Creating a reference to locations (locRef is my attempt, I get the error "database is not defined")
2. Iterating through the locations (using the forEach function?)

Here is my index.js

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');

    exports.compareLocations = functions.database
        .ref('/students/{studentID}/class/{date}/ScannedOut')
        .onWrite(event => {
            console.log("function began execution");
            if (event.data.val() != "Yes") {
                return;
            }

            if (event.data.val() == "Yes") {
                console.log("scanned out value equal to yes");
                const loc = event.data.val();

                const locRef = event.data.ref.parent.child('locations').data;

                var insideCount = 0;
                var totalCount = 0;

                const region = [[coordinateA],[coordinateB],[coordinateC],[coordinateD]];

                locRef.data.forEach(function(snapshot) {
                    var location = snapshot.val();
                    console.log("iterating through "+location);
                    var x = location.latitude;
                    var y = location.longitude;
                    console.log(x, y);
                    var point = [x, y];
                    if (inside(point, region)) {
                        insideCount = insideCount + 1;
                    }
                    totalCount = totalCount + 1;
                }, this);

                return event.data.ref.set(insideCount);
            }

        });
```

Comment: I guess you should wait for the `locRef` to resolve, something along the lines of `event.data.ref.parent.child('locations').once('value').then(snapshot => {...})` - See the [DeltaSnapshot#ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#ref) documentation for more information.

Comment: You might want to take a look at some of the official sample code that shows how to query the database in a function: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/